# Three.JS: How to make textures overlap each other?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, textures, overlapping

TL;DR: How do i make textures appear bigger than the faces they are attached to, with a fading effect, so that all textures overlap each other?

-

Learning three.js by trying to recreate the Game [Warzone 2100](http://wz2100.net/). :)

I'm loading a default texture for the ground with:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('tile-53.png'); // Specify file
texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; // Make the texture repeat
texture.repeat.set(map_width, map_height); // Repeat for every face
texture.anisotropy = 100; // Disable anisoptropy
```

At the moment it looks like [this](http://img4.picload.org/image/oaapcpl/bildschirmfoto.jpg). Now compare it to [this](https://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/warzone2100/screenshots/219752.jpg).

Warzone 2100 finally started looking good with the new renderer especially because they made the textures show bigger than the faces and overlap each other, making the sharp borders vanish. Is it possible to reach the same effect with three.js and if so, how would i go there?

Answer (score 2):

Texture is something that is attached to it's geometry in the first place (speaking about 3D), so to make just the texture itself overlap other textures is not quite possible. You can perfectly make your geometries overlap each other, though.

For your textures looking "bigger", try looking [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1847).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately i already found that, it didn't help. I don't understand what it does but it at least can not help with what i want. However, i understand what you mean with "overlapping geometries" in the sense of that i don't use a single planeGeometry but thousands of small ones. But wouldn't that destroy the map as there would be edges everywhere, making collision detection impossible? Since the geometries have to be bigger than they must be for the map... Maybe i should ask the Developers of Warzone 2100 how they did it and try to recreate it in ThreeJS.

Comment: When I was in to game development, the way we did it was this: we generated terrain mesh for our game scene from a bitmap image and then applied to it several textures, each one covering the whole terrain. That way it looked pretty similar to your image from Warzone. So, I guess, in three.js you could do just the same - create your terrain and then use just one texture, wrapping it many times along X and Y axis. For further help - you could provide jsfiddle example of what you have right now for us to assist you.